# python for loop and line splitting on text file

Tags: python

I am trying to split a text file into separate files based on the sample ID listed in the first column. For example, I have this input `variant_file`:

```
SAMPLE_ID CHROM POS REF ALT
Sample1 chr1 123 G T
Sample1 chr2 456 A C
Sample1 chr3 789 C T
Sample2 chr1 123 G A
Sample3 chr2 123 G C
Sample3 chr3 456 G A
```

And I would like to have this output:

Sample1:

```
#CHROM POS REF ALT
chr1 123 G T
chr2 456 A C
chr3 789 C T
```

Sample2:

```
#CHROM POS REF ALT
chr1 123 G A
```

Sample3:

```
#CHROM POS REF ALT
chr2 123 G C
chr3 456 G A
```

My code splits each sample into separate files, however, if more than one instance of a sample exists in the SAMPLE_ID column, the header `#CHROM POS REF ALT` is repeated.

```
def create_vcf(variant_file):
    with open(variant_file, "r") as f:
        next(f)
        for line in f.readlines():
            line = line.strip()
            sample_list = {line.split()[0]}
            chrom = "chr" + line.split()[1]
            pos = line.split()[2]
            ref = line.split()[3]
            alt = line.split()[4]
            for sample_name in sample_list:
                out_vcf = open(DIR_NAME + "/" + "output" + "/" + str(sample_name) + "/" + str(sample_name) + ".vcf", "a")
                out_vcf.write('#CHROM\tPOS\tREF\tALT\t' + sample_name + "\n")
                out = [chrom, pos, ref, alt]
                out_vcf.write("\t".join(out) + "\n")
```

Outputs the following for Sample1:

```
#CHROM  POS     ID      REF     ALT  
chr1    123     .       G       T      
#CHROM  POS     ID      REF     ALT
chr2    456     .       A       C
#CHROM  POS     ID      REF     ALT
chr3    789     .       C       T
```

How do I ensure the header is only prepended once?

Comment: Are you sure? It works for me...

Comment: @kosciej16, I've retested with a similar input and get the same result...I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: @kosciej16, my mistake...I realized I was opening the outfile with the "w" option instead of "a" for append previously.

Comment: You can reply to your own question with the solution and mark it resolved :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed [open](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) write mode `w` in `out_vcf` to append mode `a`. Corrected in function `create_vcf()` above.